# File Appending with BinaryWriter

Tags: c#

I have written a simple utility function to gather a bunch of text, so that after a few rounds, I can open the text file and see the content.

```
public static void Accumulate(string text, string path)
{
    var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);

    using ( var binary = new BinaryWriter(file) )
    {
        binary.Write(text);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

However, when I use a delimiter to separate the output of each run, it does not take effect. For example, I changed the writer line to `binary.Write(text + "\n");` and then `binary.Write(text , "\n");` and also tried:

```
binary.Write(text);
binary.Write("\n");
file.Close();
```

But none actually works, which is probably because this is a binary writer, and not a literal text writer. Correct?

Is there anyway to modify this very program and add a new blank line in between the outputs; i.e. jump to the next line after every writing?

Also, I wonder if I should use `file.Flush()` instead of `file.Close()` or perhaps both? Which one would ensure proper disposing after writing?

Comment: You understand, that when you write string via `BinaryWriter` it'll put binary encoded string length into stream before text itself? Why not use `StreamWriter` if you work only with text?

Comment: BinaryWriter strictly writes binary data, not text.  You have to use BinaryReader to correctly read that file back.  Zero odds that whatever program that reads the text file uses that class.  Bummer if you happen to write a string that is 26 characters long for example, most any program that expects a real text file will interpret the byte that BinaryWriter writes to encode the string length as end-of-file.  Use File.OpenText() instead to get somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"` so that new line works.
So use this:

```
binary.Write(text + "\r\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer! Do you also know if I should use `Flush` instead of (or as well as) `Close`?

Comment: @Joshua in this case you should not use `Close` as you have placed writer into `using` statement which will automatically `Close` writer. Using `Flush` is not a bad habit as it clears buffer and causes any buffered data to be written.

Comment: Many thanks. Just one last silly question: In `binary.Write(text + "\r\n")` the new-line definitely executes after all the text (i.e. data) has been written. Right? At the very end, before the file being close. Correct?

Comment: @Joshua this will write your `text` string and after that will write '"\r\n"'.

Answer (score 0):

A binary writer writes bytes, so you should be using:

```
binary.Write (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (text + "\n"));
```

Comment: This is not solving his issue